# 3 short beeps continuously

Tags: bios

I have old IBM Thinkpad R31. It boots up and Windows XP working normal, but all the time I hear 3 short beeps continuously.  ???

Comment: So it beeps 3 times continously all the time even while booted into Windows?

Comment: Does it beep before/during the boot?

Answer (score 5):

You can find the meaning of beep errors here: [**Lenovo Support**](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-39706.html). To be specific:

```
3 short beeps   Post error
3 long beeps    System POST: Critical Thermal
```

Comment: Hmm... 3 short beeps would be a POST error so I doubt that Windows would actually boot successfully. 3 Long beeps means some type of thermal problem, so maybe that's it?

Comment: @joeqwerty, agree. Seems like some cleaning of the cooler fan is required.